# backgroundColor for TableViewCell not working

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, background-image

[image]

like you see in the picture, i have a tableView ( view of a tableviewController ), the blue view is a headerView for section, when i tap it, it collapse some cells, but my problem is that cells have the first part of the backGround of the tableView (the cloud) as background [ in this pic i set the backgroundColor of cell to clear but if i set a color to it the right and left (L R in pic) part still there]

i try : cell.layer.masksToBounds = YES; and cell.contentView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

How can i solve that? and why the cell take the first part of tableView BackGroundColor [image] as BackGroundColor ?

Edit : some codes ( i'm overwriting all values in StoryBoard like backGround ...)

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"clientCell";
    ClientCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if ([[[[[[DataManager sharedManager] clientsList] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectForKey:@"rewards"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"description"] != [NSNull null])
  {
    cell.voucherDescription.text = [[[[[[DataManager sharedManager] clientsList]    objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectForKey:@"rewards"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"description"];
  }

 //configure more labels ..

[cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[cell.voucherDescription setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:SharkFontSystemeName size:17]];    
return cell;
}
```

in viewDidLoad :

```
 [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.png"]]];
```

Comment: Try to add image view to cell as addsubview and you can set frame for your image view as well, according to your requirement.

Comment: this doesn't work,i think the problem is not 'just' in cell because if i use a color instead "colorWithPatternImage:" that seems to work fine.

Comment: Please add your code as well to understand your problem in better way.

Comment: i edit my question with some code.

Comment: Try by increasing your custom cell width and/or your uitableview width

Comment: i'm using storyBoard, and the tableView is the principal view for the viewController so width is set to 320 and cell the same, but i try your suggestion and doesn't work.

i have 3 tableViewController, all have the same problem !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem resolve, i change the viewController from an UITableViewController to an UIViewController and add a tableView as a subView, and without changing anyThing in code that work perfectly.
is this a bug or i miss something ?